# (Linux, terminal, key mapping) 'Home' & 'End' key are not recognized in neovim built-in terminal-emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, nvim

Previously I used vim editor for python, c++ code.
As the code gets longer and complex, it is hard to write code without ide.

So I installed neovim  and the problem is 'home' and 'end' key doesn't work at all. The weird thing is it works for vim editor but it doesn't work in neovim.

There are several similar questions and the solutions mostly about the key mapping. But my situation is a little bit different.
As followed by previously suggested solutions, Ctrl-V 'Home/End' key must print something like [[1~. But in my case, it doesn't print anything. It seems neovim considers I don't have'home/end' key..

I am not expert on linux system, maybe I didn't properly understand the previous solution...

Thank you in advance.

FYI,
-echo $TERM  ==> xterm
-I tried the test 'Ctrl-V home/key' in the neovim terminal-emulator( :terminal )